# Can't run 'kill -- -$$' in my shell script when I sudo it

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill

I have a shell script that starts a couple of background child processes.  I want them to always be running - unless the parent process quits or gets killed (so I have the children in a loop that just always restarts if it quits).

This script seems to work relatively well, if I execute it directly.  But as soon as I `sudo` it, it will not clean up the other processes properly:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

# Start first background thing
while true;
do
        sleep 1
        echo "SOME PROCESS RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND"
        echo "SHOULD AUTO-RESTART IF IT GETS KILLED OR CRASHES"
        sleep 5
done &

# Start second background thing
while true;
do
        sleep 3
        echo "ANOTHER ONE..."
        sleep 3
done &

# Wait for quit keypress
while true
do
        echo "Press 'Q' to quit"
        read -rsn1
        if [ $REPLY == "q" ] || [ $REPLY == "Q" ]; then
                echo "Are you sure? [Y/N]"
                read -rsn1
                if [ $REPLY == "y" ] || [ $REPLY == "Y" ]; then
                        kill -- -$$
                        exit
                fi
        fi
        echo ""
        sleep 1
done

# Wait
wait
```

When I'm sudo'ing, if I press CTRL+C, or press "Q" to quit, it will exit the parent (main) process but not the children and I receive this error:

```
adam@TG-BBCAM-01:~ $ sudo ./temp.sh
Press 'Q' to quit
Are you sure? [Y/N]
./temp.sh: line 31: kill: (-29098) - No such process
./temp.sh: line 1: kill: (-29098) - No such process
adam@TG-BBCAM-01:~ $ SOME PROCESS RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND
SHOULD AUTO-RESTART IF IT GETS KILLED OR CRASHES
ANOTHER ONE...
SOME PROCESS RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND
SHOULD AUTO-RESTART IF IT GETS KILLED OR CRASHES
ANOTHER ONE...
SOME PROCESS RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND
SHOULD AUTO-RESTART IF IT GETS KILLED OR CRASHES
ANOTHER ONE...
SOME PROCESS RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND
```

Obviously because it didn't kill the children, they're still running and flooding my shell still with output.  When I don't sudo, it works great.

It seems to be the `kill -- -$$` in both the trap and the "keypress monitor" part of my script.  Commenting one out doesn't fix the other one.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  I would just like it to work in most any situation (well at least, sudo or not).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `kill -- -"$pgid"`, that is it has to be a process *group* id. `kill -- -"$$"` would only work if the shell was the process group leader which it's not when running with `sudo` from an interactive shell:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'ps -j; exit'
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
26786 26786 29719 pts/39   00:00:00 sudo
26794 26786 29719 pts/39   00:00:00 bash
26795 26786 29719 pts/39   00:00:00 ps
```

`sudo` is the process group leader, not `bash`.

So, you'd need to do `kill -- -"$(ps -o pgid= -p "$$")"` or simply:

```
kill 0
```

Which is the command to kill your own process group.

In any case, that's only a valid thing to do if your script is called on its own from an interactive shell (that performs job control).

Also note that in:

```
(the-script; echo "$?")
```

Or:

```
the-script | cmd
```

The subshell in the first case or `cmd` is the second are also placed in that same process group so would be killed as well by that `kill 0`.

Comment: If my shell's PID is less than 5 digits long, `ps` will left-pad it with spaces. A more robust solution would be [...] `-o pgid:1=` [...], which will set the column width to 1 character and remove the extra whitespace.